# Framework not found when archive

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I am facing an issue when i am only trying to do archive.There is no problem when building and running the project.We are working on a project and other developer's macbook is m1 and maybe this can leads to a problem, i am not sure about that.

I tried to:

- Pod deintegrate and pod install
- Clean build folder

[image: XCode error screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried completely removing the /Pods folder and doing pod install again?